# Service Worker Cache not storing all files in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, caching, service-worker, web-frontend

I am currently working on a project that involves the creation of an offline application with a realitivly big amount of files stored in the cache. (432 to be exact)

As the files needed is dynamic for each user, I have a method that creates the Array and passes it into the service worker. This all works fine and if I simply print the array it contains the full list of files.

The problem arises when I check the cache storage after the everything is loaded, for some reason a total of 49 files is being stored with no promt as to what happened to the rest of the files.

I am using Firefox, and am aware that the cache has unlimited storage with promts after 50mb. The total memory used after storing these 49 files is just under 19mb, so I do not believe it to be a memory issue.

I have searched through Service Worker questions and haven't found anyone experiancing the same issue, so I hope someone out here can help!

- Cheers :)

Comment: I don't know what the problem might be, but I suggest you try to separately log (console.log) from the SW each individual caching operation (initiating fetch, getting the response, putting it into the cache etc) and seeing where it goes wrong. Are you using some utility library in the SW? Try to inspect the SW and the Caches storage with Chrome dev tools (not sure how mature they're on FF side).

Comment: This problem is not arising on a fetch event, but on the manual loading of files into a cache. (Similar to how files are loaded in the install event, just done later in the lifecycle as these files are created after the install event has fired) I have logged the array right before it should be added to the cache, and it is the full array - Then there is no indication of why the full array is not stored into the cache. No libraries being used due to the nature of the application and unfortuantly due to support issues the application does not run on Chrome.

Comment: I know Chrome's Cache Storage DevTools viewer loads in 50 results at once, and then makes you click an arrow to move to the next page of 50 results. Firefox might do that as well, and perhaps it explains what you're seeing? You can check the full cache contents in DevTools via JavaScript using `caches.open('my-cache-name').then(cache => cache.keys()).then(requests => requests.map(request => request.url)).then(console.log)`

Comment: This was it! Spent a few days trying to fix my code which turned out to be correct the whole time. Firefox is missing that little arrow to go to page two of the cache. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff Posnick said, Chrome Devtools displays 50 entries at a time (0-49).
At the bottom, it should say the total number of entries like: `Total entries: xxx`